Install framework-dependent .NET 8 application with msix
When I set up an msix install for a .NET 8 application, it does a stand-alone setup by default. Is there a way to have msix package a framework-dependent install?
The stand-alone install with msix is about 70MB, while the framework-dependent (with Inno Setup) is 2MB. With the amount of downloads we get, the data transfer fees will kill us with stand-alone setups.

At the moment there seems to be no built-in solution for declaring .NET as a dependency package.
Here is a thread from MS with more details
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/51574

Thanks Bogdan. It seems to be another case of Microsoft leaving things half-done.
